# Add an image located in my project with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This is my logic tree:

[image]

**consultaBeneficiario.js** below

This is a callback of datatable plugin:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function () {

        $("tbody td.xls").each(function(){              
            $(this).html("<img src='../plusDetails.png' onclick = 'dettaglioConsultaPagamentiXLS("+$(this).html()+", \"beneficiario\")\'> XLS </button>");
        });
```

But it's not working.

This is the result:

[image]

If I do, for example:

```
$(this).html("<img src='http://i.imgur.com/SD7Dz.png' onclick = 'dettaglioConsultaPagamentiXLS("+$(this).html()+", \"beneficiario\")\'> XLS </button>");
```

works.

I'm using thymeleaf if it can help.

Why?

Comment: did u try with static link to your image ?

Comment: Relative image paths are based on the HTML page location, not where your script file is located.

Comment: The opening tag is 'img' but the closing tag is 'button' !...

Comment: There is a `</img>` tag in the spec, but it is not mandatory. Images can be inserted just with a single `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Because the '../' is interpreted from your main html/php document not from the location of your script. Set full url (you can define it / or grab it as a jquery variable)

Comment: This is a Spring project.. Just now, I was thinking if it's possible use '../', it is?

Answer (score 0):

try using a baseurl variable like

```
var BASEURL = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+((window.location.port=='') ? '' : ':'+window.location.port)+'/';
```

After that you can use that to set a static link for the image

```
$(this).html("<img src='"+BASEURL+"pagamenti/plusDetails.png' onclick = 'dettaglioConsultaPagamentiXLS("+$(this).html()+", \"beneficiario\")\'></img>");
```